# When working with a C API, use character arrays or use strings and convert as needed?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm working with a C API and a lot of the functions take arguments that are character arrays. I've heard that using `char` arrays is now frowned upon. But on the other hand, using `c_str()` to convert the string to a `char` array over-and-over seems wasteful.

Are there any reasons to do it one way vs the other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `c_str()` call is quite likely to be inlined—it's very small in terms of the required code. I would use `std::string` if that's the only thing holding you back.

Of course, if you're very worried, this standard advice applies:

1. Profile it
2. Read the assembly

Also be aware that this is a micro-optimization; you're quite likely to be wasting development time worrying about something completely different than from what you should be worrying about.

Answer (score 2):

Most implementations of `std::string` probably store the actual string as a C string anyway, so the `c_str` function is just an inline function that returns a pointer. So generally, I would say the proper way to go is with `std::string`.

Of course, if the string is intended to be modified by the function you call, then you can't use the `std::string` approach. Instead, you'll have to make a copy to your own buffer before calling the function, in which case using arrays may be the way to go.

Comment: If you're crafty, you can still use std::string as a buffer in C++11.  'mystr.resize(buffsize);' and then  '&mystr[0]'

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, `c_str()` is going to be inlined. But what hasn't been mentioned but what I think is one of the most important aspects of your question is that `std::string` follows the principles of RAII. When using `std::string`, you won't need to remember to free the string or need to worry about exception safety. **Just make sure each instance of `std::string` is not destructed until the C code is done with the string.**  That could especially be an issue if the `std::string` is a temporary made by the compiler.

If your C function writes back a string, you could use a `vector<char>` and set the size to your desired buffer size.  That way you'll still follow C++ RAII principles.

Comment: Or just use a `std::string` in lieu of the `vector<char>` and size it properly too.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Before everyone jumps and uses std::string for C functions that modify a string, remember you can't use c_str(), which returns a read-only const char C-style string.  So you have to use e.g. &s[0] to get pointer to first character.  Is that memory contiguous?  Read http://herbsutter.com/2008/04/07/cringe-not-vectors-are-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous/ --- vector was always guaranteed to be contiguous, but not string.  (See the comment further down when someone asked Herb about strings.)

Comment: The rules changed with C++11: **n3485: 21.4.1** *(5) The char-like objects in a basic_string object shall be stored contiguously. That is, for any `basic_string` object `s`, the identity `&*(s.begin() + n) == &*s.begin() + n` shall hold for all values of `n` such that `0 <= n < s.size()`.* Note the strict inequality, while `s[s.size()]` is valid and must return `'\0'`, when using pointers into the buffer there is no such guarantee. Prior to C++11, the most common `std::string` implementations already provided the guarantee (libstdc++'s and dirkumware's)

Comment: Sure, but that was an implementation-specific detail, not guaranteed by the standard.  So if you want to write the most portable non-C++11 code, you'd have to refrain from using string is how I read this...

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you're doing, and what the interface functions are
doing.  At one extreme, I don't think anyone would recommend converting
a string literal to an `std::string`, just so you can call `c_str` on
it.  At the other: any code building up strings dynamically should use
`std::string`.  Functions like `strcpy` and `strcat` are invitations to
buffer overflow.  Between two, it depends.  I'd say that the criteria
should be ease and safety: anytime something is easier or safer to do
using `std::string`, use `std::string`.  As long as what you're doing
doesn't require dynamic allocation of `char[]`, and things like
`operator+` on strings wouldn't be used, you can use `char[]`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple reason to use `string`: **it works**.

Working with C-strings is a pain:

- manual memory allocation and deallocation is error-prone
- the interface itself is error-prone (lack of null character termination, off-by-one errors and buffer overflows are common)
- the operations are inefficient (`strlen`, `strcpy` and `strcat`) because the length need be recomputed at each time

I really see no good reason to *ever* work with C-strings.

It's such a pain that many platforms have provided their own specific operations and that a number of "better strings" have been proposed (oh, the joy of having multiple standards).